# String numbers into number numbers in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers

How come when I set 00 as a value like this:

$var = 00;

it ouputs as 0 when I use it? How can I set 00 so that $var++ would become 01?

Comment: Numbers with trailing zeroes are used to specify octal values (instead of base-10 decimals) - I don't think this is what you want to do. What do you want to do? Usually, it's better to add zeroes when outputting the variable, but do additions etc. with normal integers

Comment: You're asking two separate and unrelated questions here. You should divide them up into separate questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numbers in PHP (and virtually all languages) are not stored internally with leading (or in the case of decimal values, trailing) zeros.

There are many ways to display your numeric variables with leading zeros In PHP. The simplest way is to convert your value to a string, and pad the string with zero's until it's the correct length. PHP has a function called [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to do this for you:

```
$var = 0;
$var += 1;

// outputs '01'
echo str_pad($var, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Alternatively, the [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) family of functions have a specifier for printing zero-padded values:

```
$var = 1;

// outputs '01'
printf("%02d", $var);
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter for 00, but for 01, etc. php will try to save the number as octal.

Answer (score 3):

Using a function like [`printf`](http://php.net/printf) or [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) will do this much more easily for you.

```
$number = 1;
printf("%02d", $number); // Outputs 01

$number = 25;
printf("%02d", $number); // Outputs 25
```

You can set the minimum width by replacing the two with another number.

Comment: So: `$number = 25;
printf("%04d", $number); // Outputs 0025?`

Answer (score 1):

Also number_format() is your friend in formatting numbers.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Great for ensuring there are 2 decimals for example.