# How to format numbers with 00 prefixes in php?

Tags: php, numbers, format

I'm trying to generate invoice numbers. They should always be 4 numbers long, with leading zeros, for example :

- 1 -> Invoice 0001
- 10 -> Invoice 0010
- 150 -> Invoice 0150

etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate? -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963271/string-numbers-into-number-numbers-in-php

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use [str_pad()](http://php.net/str_pad).

`$invID = str_pad($invID, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: I like this answer better than mine - I think both should work - this just seems to fit the problem better.

Comment: @Dave Using `printf` functions is an equally valid way to do it here, but since Invoice IDs won't be used as numbers (mathematically speaking), treating them as strings like this is simply another way to do it. If there were ever non-numeric Invoice IDs (e.g., "order 001F3"), then string it is.

Comment: @Wiseguy, thanks that worked even better than printf because I had to add a prefix to the numbers also, like INV0023.

Comment: @mike23 Glad to help, though I'm not sure why this would be any easier to add 'INV'.

Comment: Ack, but strings can also be padded with `printf('INV%04s',$something);`. Then again: if the invoice if the only fixed width thing you need, this solution is indeed better. If you need more fields on a line to be fixed-width (writing to fixed width files etc.), `printf` would probably be a better solution.

Comment: @Wrikken Exactly. One assumption I had was that the invoice ID would be used standalone at this point, possibly to save to a DB column and whatnot.

Comment: _If_ it was for a MySQL DB column, I'd have mentioned the `ZEROFILL` attribute :)

Comment: @Wrikken, you're right. At first I had tried `$inv = "INV" . printf('%04s',$num)`, which didn't work. That's why I chose Wiseguy's solution. But in the end it seems there are Many ways to do the same thing here.

Comment: @mike23 Ah, I see. [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf) actually outputs the string (like `print` or `echo` does); [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) works identically but _returns_ the string rather than prints it. You'd want `sprintf()`.

Comment: @Wiseguy, thanks for the clarification, I'm pretty new to printf/sprint.

Comment: @mike23 Everybody's new at some point. Glad to see you're learning quickly. :-)

Comment: I got my solution. Thank You.

Answer (score 30):

Use `sprintf`: http://php.net/function.sprintf

```
$number = 51;
$number = sprintf('%04d',$number);
print $number;
// outputs 0051


$number = 8051;
$number = sprintf('%04d',$number);
print $number;
// outputs 8051
```

Comment: perhaps because I explicitly wrote that the strings should be 4 chars long in the end, and you cite two examples with 8 chars.

Comment: pfft, change the 8 to a 4... I was demonstrating the concept.

Comment: is sprintf (memory, cpu ) faster then str_pad and thread safe?

Answer (score 12):

Use (s)[`printf`](http://www.php.net/printf)

```
printf('%04d',$number);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$x = 1;
sprintf("%03d",$x);
echo $x;
```

Answer (score 4):

`printf()` works fine if you are always printing something, but `sprintf()` gives you more flexibility.  If you were to use this function, the `$threshold` would be **4**.

```
/**
 * Add leading zeros to a number, if necessary
 *
 * @var int $value The number to add leading zeros
 * @var int $threshold Threshold for adding leading zeros (number of digits 
 *                     that will prevent the adding of additional zeros)
 * @return string
 */
function add_leading_zero($value, $threshold = 2) {
    return sprintf('%0' . $threshold . 's', $value);
}

add_leading_zero(1);      // 01
add_leading_zero(5);      // 05
add_leading_zero(100);    // 100
add_leading_zero(1);      // 001
add_leading_zero(5, 3);   // 005
add_leading_zero(100, 3); // 100
add_leading_zero(1, 7);   // 0000001
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the **str_pad** function

```
 //pad to left side of the input
$my_val=str_pad($num, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)

//pad to right side of the input
$my_val=str_pad($num, 3, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT)

//pad to both side of the input
$my_val=str_pad($num, 3, '0', STR_PAD_BOTH)
```

where $num is your number

Comment: it work for me, simple excelent

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( strlen($invoice_number) < 4 ) $invoice_num = '0' . $invoice_num;
```

Comment: Doing this will just result in the zeros being stripped off the next time anything in PHP casts it to a int/float. Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php to see why this is a bad idea :)