# dynamic divs in php

Tags: php, counter, bootstrap-4, css-counter

Want to create a counter for dynamic value from the database. Like if I am getting `$count` as `1` then it shows only two div like First for `0` and second for `1`. If I am getting `$count` value `50` then it should show me 3 divs like `0`, `5` and `0`. For multiple count values how can I make it dynamic for the `$count` value?

Given below I have attached an image like if I am getting this no then how can I separate this no to all dynamic div.

Comment: Please paste your code

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
<?php
 $count=1264553;
 $array = str_split($count);
  echo "<div>0 </div>";
 foreach($array as $value){
echo "<div>".$value."</div>";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to me,
you should first convert your count to 3 digit number:
[How to format numbers with 00 prefixes in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296822/how-to-format-numbers-with-00-prefixes-in-php)

Than convert 3 digits number to string and split it to an array of letters:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Iterate over the array and generate divs as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this in php by embbed html code in php.
You can use `while` or `for` or `foreach` , any of them. Example code is follows :

With while :

```
$count=1;
$i=0;
while($i < $count){
echo "<div>".$count."</div>";
$i++;
}
```

With for loop :

```
$count=1;
for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++){
echo "<div>".$count."</div>";
}
```

With foreach :

Here we have to use array

```
$count=1;
$array = str_split($count);
echo "<div>0 </div>";
foreach($array as $value){
echo "<div>".$value."</div>";
 }
```

Any more clearification if need please let me know.